# Postgres Group by like fuzzy logic

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count

I want to group by data present table. but the problem in all names is similar not the same.

```
id    name             subject_id
---------------------------------
1     Ganeash          1
2     Ganesha P         2
3     Shree Ganesh Pai 1
4     Gaanesh shree G   1
5     Ramesh shri      2
```

In this data everywhere Ganesh is common so the output should contain.

```
name    count
-------------
Ganesh  4
Ramesh  1
```

If I use **soundex** function.

```
postgres=# SELECT soundex('hello world!');
ERROR:  function soundex(unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT soundex('hello world!');
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: I have edited table data please check it now.

Comment: Hard task. You probably need word index (eg your third name generates three entries), then some function like soundex(), which can make similar words comparable and then you can group (cluster) by this function result over word index/table. I know that my idea is fuzzy also :)

Comment: I get the error on Soundex() so I asked that question is there any other way to solve that.

Comment: Soundex() was simply an example of function (implemented in T-SQL), able to remove some differences from single words. It may have no direct counterpart in PostgreSQL, but there can be better functions for similar task.

Comment: soundex(...) is provided by the extension fuzzystrmatch (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/fuzzystrmatch.html)

Comment: Why should it contain Ramesh and Ganesh and not Shri or Pai?  Are you looking for something that understands what traditional given and traditional last names are in your culture?

Comment: @jjanes I got the solution if we use soundex() it gives the result as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `CASE`

```
select name,count(*) from (
    select case when name like '%Ganesh%' THEN 'Ganesh'
                when name like '%Ramesh%' THEN 'Ramesh' end as name
    from test) a
group by name
```

[***Check Demo Here***](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=871d67a4c6bb7f944a6295f2750a214f)

*Output*

[image]

Comment: Don't pass names over there.

Comment: @krashan, now that you had installed, you can replace `LIKE` in my query with `SOUNDEX` and try to group similar rows. For eg., `when soundex(name)=soundex('ganesh') then 'A'` something like this

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple, you just need to split the text field into an array of words and then `unnest` the arrays into rows. Then you manipulate the rows using standard SQL (`count()`, `GROUP BY`, etc.):

```
SELECT count(*), 
       unnest(regexp_split_to_array(name, E'\\s+')) AS name2
  FROM names 
 GROUP BY name2
 ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I found a solution to use Soundex() function